# How to assign a value to your class in parameters of method?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[class and method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEwtD.png)
I have a method and a class and I need to be able to assign my own parameters to any button
[there must be my parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHpHT.png)
Perhaps I need a method that can take 2 arguments and create an instance of the class MP_data

when I created a method with 2 arguments in Unity it is not visible

Comment: onclick doesnt take paramters.. so you have to make an onclick that will collect parameters and then call the method

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Unity Editor does not allow to pass 2 params directly to events. Secondly, your fields have get-set so it's a property, properties never visible in inspector. But you can make something like this:

```
[System.Serializable] //serialize class to be visible in editor
public class MP_Data
{
  public GameObject movingPanel;
  public int numberChild;
}

[SerializeField] MP_data Data;

public void open_close_panel()
{
   //your code based on Data
}
```

Then you will set MP_Data in component and attach empty method to event.